# display image in new page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had soluation which display images and I want when click on displayed image to display in new page with it,s original size.So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply link directly to the image, if you just want the image to display.

```
<a href="path to image"><img src="path to image" alt="" target="_blank" /></a>
```

`target="_blank"` will open it in a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect one of the images on stackoverflow by [Firebug](http://GetFireBug.com) and change the `href` of `a` tag

```
<a title="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" 
     href="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3099.jpg">
  <img width="220" height="250" border="0" alt="" title="" 
         src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3099.jpg">
</a>
```